# Compile-time array bounds

Tags: .net, arrays, type-systems

In studying the internals of the CLI, I notice that it is possible for type signatures to specify array bounds (at compile time.)  For instance, instead of having:

`Byte[,]`

We can have:

`Byte[1...100,1...]`

If I am not mistaken it is not possible to actually declare types like the latter in either C# or C++/CLI.  Furthermore, ECMA-335 indicates:

> The VES creates one array type for each distinguishable array type. In general, array types are only distinguished by the type of their elements and their rank.

The Common Language Specification (CLS) imposes a number of restrictions, including:

> Only the fact that an item is an array and the element type of the array shall be
>   required to distinguish between overloads.

So it seems that support for compile-time array bounds is present at the lowest levels of the CLI but not elsewhere.  This leads me to wonder:

- When would a type signature including this information ever be created/encountered in practice?  Are there .NET languages that *do* emit this?  EDIT: There are languages that probably *do* use one-based arrays normally - but do they encode this into the type signatures?
- Where does the CLI actually *use* this information if it *is* present?  (This in particular is of interest to me as I'm designing a CLI implementation.)

As far as I can see, any array is created either using the `newarr` bytecode instruction for vectors, or `Array.CreateInstance` for the general case.  Neither of these mechanisms accept a type signature for *the array itself*, so creation it seems cannot use this information.

Theoretically, this information could be useful to optimize array access by inlining efficient machine code to compute the address.  However, `ldelem` and friends only access simple vectors; multi-dimensional array access requires a method call, which makes me think such an optimization probably doesn't take place.

I have to think there is some purpose for this mechanism, in order for it to have made it into an international standard, but I'm not really seeing it.

Comment: As a comment, as this is just my personal conjecture: Some languages allow custom array start indices, as opposed to C-based languages that C# was modelled after. The CLI supports those custom start indices nonetheless and compilers for Pascal-based languages such as [Oxygene](http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/) or [A#](http://asharp.martincarlisle.com/) may very well emit that kind of arrays. Non-zero-based arrays can actually be created in C# with reflection with [this overload of `Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Oh, and the information will quite certainly be used by the CLI at least when the [`Array.GetLowerBound` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is invoked.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I had a feeling there might be some language that would use such bounds.. however, note the `Array.CreateInstance` overload you mention actually takes the bounds as arguments and therefore does _not_ use that information from the _type signature_.  Likewise, `Array.GetLowerBound` is accessing information about a _runtime instance_.  I know straightforwardly non-zero bases can be used at _runtime_ - my concern is more towards why this information can be included statically in _type signatures_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information only appears in the signature of the array type, it is not available at runtime without accessing the array object members.  This is important for languages that consider arrays with different bounds to be distinct types, the Pascal language is an example of that.  It treats a variable of type `array[1..10] of integer` as distinct and incompatible with a variable of type `array[1..11] of integer`.

Comment: Now that you put it that way I was able to find some quotes in the spec that add some clarity.. mind if I add them to your answer?